# specialize a template with expression parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class like this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo;
```

I want to have a specialization of

```
template <>
class Foo < size_t N >;
```

but that doesn't compiles for me:

my main is like:

```
Foo<int> p;  // OK
Foo<15> p2;  // fails to compile
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your second `Foo` is not a specialization, it is an entirely different template (it does not take the same kind of parameter). Unlike functions, templates cannot be overloaded (I don't know if there is a good reason for this limitation, though. If anyone has an explanation, I'll be happy to hear it.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't - your template takes one type parameter, always. Specializations can only be more special than that, but not *different* (hence the name).

Maybe you can use an auxiliary template to store value information:

```
template <typename T, T Val> struct ValueWrapper { };

template <typename T> struct Foo;

templaet <typename T, T Val> struct Foo<ValueWrapper<T, Val>>
{
    typedef T type;
    static type const value = Val;

    // ...
};
```

Usage:

```
Foo<char> x;
Foo<ValueWrapper<int, 15>> y;
```

Comment: How about [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)?

Comment: @LucTouraille: Sure, why not :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are three kinds of template parameters: Those that represent a type (e.g. `class T` or `typename T`), those that represent a non-type (e.g. `int N` or `size_t N`), and those that represent a template (e.g. `template <class T2> class T`).

The parameter defined for your template is of the first kind (a type parameter), but the specialization assumes the second kind (a non-type parameter). That doesn't work. The parameters of the specialization must be of the same kind as the corresponding parameters of the primary template definition.

Comment: To put it in perspective, here's a sample, with redundant template arguments: http://ideone.com/fxKM6

Comment: @jogojapan: "three kinds of templates" - it's more a case of kinds of template parameters... any given template can mix and match parameters of those "kinds".

Comment: @TonyDelroy True. My answer implicitly assumed there is only one template parameter, because that was the case in the OP's example. I have reworded it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can specialize the class using an intermediate class:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  static const bool is_number = false;
};
template <size_t number>
struct ic
{};
template <size_t N>
class Foo < class ic<N> >
{
public:
   static const bool is_number = true;
   size_t getN() const
   {
      return N;
   } 
};

int main()
{
   Foo<int> p;  
   Foo<ic<15> > p2;  
   cout << "p.is_number = " << p.is_number << endl;
   cout << "p2.is_number = " << p2.is_number  << endl;
   cout << "p2.getN() = " << p2.getN() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```