# Generic template non-type arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I want my class to receive a non-type template argument but I don't want to specify the type of the non-type argument. I can do this by writing:

```
template<class Type, Type param>
class A
{};
```

It can then be used as follows:

```
A<int,3> a;
```

This is redundant because once I know that `param = 3` then I know that `Type = int`. Is there any way of writing this so that all of the following lines compile and instantiate different types?

```
A<3> a;
A<3.0> b;
A<3.0f> c;
```

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I got 6 squares on my screen in your comment. wears his robe and wizard hat.

Comment: @Aniket I need a filler for the minimum of 15 characters requirement. I use bananas http://i.stack.imgur.com/DvRWZ.png because SO counts each one as two characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that cannot be done. The type of all non-type template arguments must be defined in the parameter, and can never be inferred from the use, i.e. you need `Type` to be *known* when the compiler analyzes the argument `Type param`.

Comment: @BenjyKessler: Many other people have hit the same issue, including me and some really smart people around me.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is a function object, you could do either put a function template member inside a regular clas

```
class A  
{  
public: 
    template<class Type> 
    void operator()(Type param) { }  
};
```

or wrap a class template inside a function template

```
template<class Type> 
class A  
{  
public: 
    void operator()(Type param) { }  
};

template<class Type>
void fun(Type param) 
{ 
    A<Type>()(param); 
}
```

and calling it as `A()(3)` or `fun(3)` will deduce `Type` to be `int`, and similar for the others. This is because function templates DO have their arguments deduced, but not so for class templates. So if you use your class template `A` for other purposes than a function object, you need to specify its arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use A as a function object, but that's good to know for the future.

Comment: @BenjyKessler I updated it slightly because the function template can both be inside or outside the class. The difference between class and function templates is largely historical, see e.g. this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11968994/819272) for a related aspect.